# How to extract values from column using Excel macro into another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I want to extract all "Invoice" values in new sheet (sheet2) column. Now I'm only able to get single value from Invoice (not getting all values).

Please find below code:

```
Sub MergeData()

a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To a    
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4).Value = "Rechnungen / invoices" Then 

        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 2, 4).Copy
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
        b = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 3).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate          
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Actually I am beginner with macros and I don't know how to add a loop and condition to get all values.

Layout:

[image]

Comment: Is it a merged cell or have the gridlines been removed?

Comment: Will Rechnungen always be D25? It seems not from your code. Also, how will you determine when to stop travelling down column D and E looking for invoice numbers? Is there something you can use to determine when to stop? A type of border round a cell for example? Also, can the invoices keep going across columns F etc? And same question, how would you determine when invoices stop across columns? Is there other data to the right or can you assume the last used column is where invoices must stop? Or is there a better way?

Comment: How will you determine when to stop looking down rows for invoice numbers?

Comment: I would also use Range.Find method on column D to locate the cell with  "Rechnungen / invoices"  in.

Comment: 1. Will Rechnungen always be D25? ---> No. It will vary in D column/rows. 2]how will you determine when to stop travelling down column D and E looking for invoice numbers?---> I don't know. But if we applied any condition then it will possible(Not sure).  3]Also, can the invoices keep going across columns F etc?---->It goes from D to F. 4]Is there other data to the right or can you assume the last used column is where invoices must stop?-->  Yes. F will be last.

Comment: Can we assume a cell having a thicker border would indicate the end of the possible invoice rows as per the image?

Comment: How will you determine when to stop looking down rows for invoice numbers?------> Once it will get the "Anzahl/ Quantity" value in D column then it will go to E , F.

Comment: Can we assume a cell having a thicker border would indicate the end of the possible invoice rows as per the image? -------> Yes.Sheet contains only 6 columns to fill the data. (i.e A to F  )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way of looping. I am defining the row boundaries by where text is found.

**Minimum row constraint:**

Invoices will be after the cell that contains `"Rechnungen / invoices"`

```
Set startCell = .Columns("D").Find("Rechnungen / invoices")
```

**Maximum row constraint:**

Invoices will be stop before the cell that contains `"Anzahl/ Quantity"`

```
Set endCell = .Columns("D").Find("Anzahl/ Quantity")
```

**Left to right constraint:**

Invoices are known to be between columns D and F.

**Cells with only values in:**

```
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
```

---

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim invoices As Object, currentCell As Range, startCell As Range, endCell As Range, loopRange As Range
    Set invoices = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set startCell = .Columns("D").Find("Rechnungen / invoices")
        Set endCell = .Columns("D").Find("Anzahl/ Quantity")
        If startCell Is Nothing Or endCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        If startCell.Row > endCell.Row Then Exit Sub
        Set loopRange = .Range("D" & startCell.Row + 1 & ":F" & endCell.Row - 1)
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(loopRange) = 0 Then Exit Sub
        For Each currentCell In loopRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            If Not invoices.exists(currentCell.Value) Then invoices.Add currentCell.Value, 1
        Next currentCell

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Resize(invoices.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(invoices.keys)
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes. Location will vary every time but the format will same. I got only first value from invoices using my macro.

Comment: No. "Rechnungen / invoices" be always in D column. But the values of invoices are in D , E and F column

Comment: Sorry. But i am getting error while run this code. (Error : Object variable or with block variable not set)

Comment: " If startCell Is Nothing Or endCell Is Nothing Or startCell.Row > endCell.Row Then Exit Sub"

Comment: I have edited but you need to check if the text being searched for is found. Step through with F8 and see if startCell and endCell are set meaning text is found.

Comment: If not found then check the text matches exactly. Watch out for any white space at the start or end of strings.

Comment: Now it shows "compiler error : End with without with"

Comment: run successfully. But not getting any output in sheet 2 in "A" column.

Comment: Sorry sir. But I am not getting. Could you please tell me in detail ?

Comment: Code into the code and step through pressing F8... see where the code stops . See if it exits on either of these two lines:  If startCell Is Nothing Or endCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        If startCell.Row > endCell.Row Then Exit Sub

Comment: it stops after "If startCell Is Nothing Or endCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub"

Comment: So one of those values is not found in column D. Can you check "Rechnungen / invoices"  and "Anzahl/ Quantity" are found in the column D spelt exactly as here. Same length, no hidden white space, same spelling...

Comment: Can you also confirm it is not a merged cell. – No.Its not a merged cell

Comment: Great. It's working now. Thanks a lot for your help and quick response.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for sticking through all the questions!

Answer (score 0):

## Below code is also working

```
Sub MergeData()
a = Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To a
If Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(i, 4).Value = "Rechnungen / invoices" Then
        c = 0
        For k = 4 To 6
            For J = 2 To 6
                If (IsNumeric(Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(i + J, k))) Then
                    Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(i + J, k).Copy
                    Worksheets("Tabelle2").Activate
                    b = Worksheets("Tabelle2").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                    Worksheets("Tabelle2").Cells(b + c, 3).Select
                    c = c + 1
                    ActiveSheet.Paste
                    Worksheets("Tabelle1").Activate
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End If
Next

End Sub
```